# standard wrapper value[register]:servlet.service() for servlet threw exception java.lang.nullpointerexception;

Tags: java, servlets

my program returns a null object value but i need to use the null object value for verification but because it is a servlet page and i have try block so whats happening the try catches the exception and throwing null point exception.

```
         public class login extends HttpServlet {
                protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,                          HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String pass="",value="",email_id="";
    DBObject doc;
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        a=request.getParameter("email");
        out.println(a);
        b=request.getParameter("password");
        out.println(b);
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        DB db = client.getDB("smart");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("register");
      // here when am get a email id from the user in "a"  variable it matches in the database and retrieve it if the user not in db means it have to displayed user not in database bt it showing a null pointer expection bt i need to process the null 
        doc = coll.findOne(new BasicDBObject("email_id", a));
        //obj=doc.toString();

        email_id=doc.get("email_id").toString();

        pass = doc.get("Password").toString();

         key=doc.get("Key").toString();
       //here is the problem
         if((doc.toString()) == null)
        {
           out.println("user not in db");
           System.out.println("user not  in db");

        }
   }
```

}

Comment: Most likely, the stacktrace will tell you more about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
 Did you handled the exception ? if yes why you didn't include that code?
if No please put catch block there you have to  check whether that doc is null or not if it is null print "user is not in db".

Comment: i have included catch block also but it is not working there.. what to do

Comment: please put your entire code and logs so that any one can check what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since i have posted the null pointer exception, even catch doesnot catches it, but what mistake i have done is i have verified whether it is null or not , after the response object is committed, so when i check whether the doc object is null or not, it validates but i can redirect to next page that is the problem, response is committed, so check this also while redirecting to a page